# How to get an Instagram Access Token by calling at URL

Tags: android, instagram-api

Is there any way to get Instagram access Token just by calling at the particular url but without prompting user access permission

Comment: A big NO :( you have ask user for userName and apssword for accesstoken

Answer (score 0):

No, you need to have WebView to display html from authentication url. Even scraping html won't work - Instagram builds whole Login page using JavaScript.